# Check if object T exists field-wise in queryset of T

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have an `address` objects in my app which has the usual `street`, `street_nr`, etc. fields.

Is there a better way to do this:

```
Address.objects.filter(street=data["street"],
    street_nr=data["street_nr"],
    zip_code=data["zip_code"],
    city_name=data["city_name"],
    country_name=data["country_name"]).exists()
```

Mind that I check only for the passed fields.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the key names in the data dictionary match the field names you want to query on, you can use the `**kwargs` syntax:

```
Address.objects.filter(**data)
```